# PHP - dynamic if statement within mysql while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I try to get a list of my products BUT only for products that have 1 or more in the request I send with a form before.

Here's my code:

Problem is right now, it's including only for 1 product the template BUT there are more products with quantity >=1 within this loop. Why only 1 and than stop?

`

```
$sql="SELECT id, provider FROM products";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($propdata=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{ 

if ($_REQUEST['qty' . $propdata[id]] >= 1)
{
$mid = $propdata[id];
include('file1.php');
include($propdata[provider] . '-file2-template.php');
}

}
```

`

Hope you can help, that's quite new for me. Never needed a Request within an if statement and while loop .....

Thanks!

Comment: In your SQL call, check if `qty >= 1` rather than checking in PHP. So it would look something like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE qty >= 1`

Comment: Thanks Steve for your comment but the value qty isn't saved in sql, it comes from a form. Perhaps this wasn't so clear. (List of all available products and user can choose how many he wants). I post this qty value to this form to get the details of the chosen products.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that. So you want to store the items with quantity of 1 or more in an array?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I want to include for each product that has qty >=1 a template file.

Comment: Okay, and what is your `$mid` storing?

Comment: $mid is the id of the product within the db.

Comment: @Steve sorry, found the error. I had another sql query within this include and with the same name. After removing it, the loop works fine again. Thanks for patience ;-)

Comment: @Oliver instead of using includes like that, you should look into learning OOP (object oriented programming) and separating reusable code into classes and objects.   That would limit variable scope, so a variable in one object wouldn't affect another object.

Comment: @Devon thx, I'll have a look it. Still beginner regarding PHP but you guys here help a lot!